# Partial Git deployment strategy?

Tags: git, deployment, kohana

I need to setup a Kohana dev environment that allows me to make full use of shared module / system classes across separate applications. Each application typically belonging to a different client. I use Git for source control, but am struggling to come up with a clean deployment method that will allow me to pull *only* those parts of the dev environment specific to a client / app down into that client's production environment (assuming that the client's production environment will have Git installed).

Dev enviroment:

```
- kohana
  - applications
     - clientapp1
     - clientapp2
  - modules
  - public_html
     - clientapp1
     - clientapp2
  - system
     - 3.0.1
     - 3.0.5
```

Client 1's production environment:

```
- /
 - applications
     - clientapp1
 - modules
 - public_html
     - client_app1
 - system
     - 3.0.5
```

Naturally, I want to have total control over each client "sub repo" as if it were an independent repo (in terms of gitignore, etc). I have seen topics that cover Git's [sparse checkout](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout) feature, but it seems like it may cause a few problems down the line from a maintenance point of view, and I don't like the idea of the entire repo's metadata existing in client's production environment repo.

As you can probably tell, I'm not exactly a Git poweruser, so any suggestions / wisdom are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, each of your directories (app/clientapp1, app/clientapp2, public_html/clientapp1, ...) is a **submodule**

I.e: main project git repo:

```
kohana
  - applications
  - modules
  - public_html
  - system
```

Where you add your submodules:

```
- kohana
  - applications
     - clientapp1  -> remote: /path/to/app_client1app Git repo
     - clientapp2  -> remote: /path/to/app_client2app Git repo
  - modules
  - public_html
     - clientapp1  -> remote: /path/to/pubhtml_client1app Git repo
     - clientapp2  -> remote: /path/to/pubhtml_client2app Git repo
  - system
     - 3.0.1  -> remote: /path/to/sys Git repo, tag 3.0.1
     - 3.0.5  -> remote: /path/to/sys Git repo, tag 3.0.5
```

The fact that you are using only submodules allows you:

```
- /
  - applications
     - clientapp1  -> remote: /path/to/app_client1app Git repo
  - modules
  - public_html
     - clientapp1  -> remote: /path/to/pubhtml_client1app Git repo
  - system
     - 3.0.5  -> remote: /path/to/sys Git repo, tag 3.0.5
```

- to define another main project, this time used for deployment
- work directly in special deployment branches within those submodules, allowing you to control their files in a client specific environment.
  (see [true nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194))

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Submodules seem the way to go, but it seems I may be asking too much; I don't like the idea of needing to maintain 3 separate submodule repos for each client distribution. A directory shuffle to make the dir layout more client-centric may help...

Comment: @MatW: I confirm 2 submodules cannot coexist within the same directory (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922807/creating-a-union-branch-of-a-number-of-git-branches/2925458#2925458). As you comment, reorganizing the code layout to be closer to the deployment target might be a good avenue to explore.